# Unable to determine interface signature for function

Tags: c#, function, generics, interface, signature

I have a simple interface for caching stuff which goes like this

```
public interface ICacheService
{

        T Get<T>(string cacheId, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class;
}
```

and this works for simple callback functions but in my case I need to add something a bit more complex. I think it's an anonymous type...

In the controller I am injecting a service that runs a query and this goes like this:

```
this.queryContainer.Get<ObjectQuery>().Execute(new ObjectParameters(id));
```

But of course this isn't of type Func so if I try to use my caching service, the compiler complains.

What sort of interface do I need so that I can get my caching to work?
Ideally I want to do this:

```
this.cachingService.Get<ObjectResult>(id, this.queryContainer.Get<ObjectQuery>().Execute(new ObjectParameters(id)));
```

Is it even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: What about `...Execute(new ObjectParameters(id)).Single()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need it expressed as a `Func<T>`?
Try this:

```
this.cachingService.Get<ObjectResult>(id, ()=> this.queryContainer.Get<ObjectQuery>().Execute(new ObjectParameters(id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function.

```
() => this.queryContainer...
```

It wraps your code in a function that has no arguments at returns a value. Thus it fulfils the contract for Func